# I am getting Record duplication even i am using Begin and commit Trans in Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

[image]

I am getting bulk of duplicate record even though i am using BEGIN and COMMIT TRANS.
I am getting the duplication of LRNo column. For the last 3 years it worked well, but now its making issue. Below is my stored procedure,

```
        ALTER PROC [dbo].[spBookingSave] 
        (@BookingId INT
       ,@LRNo NVARCHAR(15)
       ,@BookingDate DATETIME
       ,@ReceivedCustomerId int
       ,@SendMobileNo nvarchar(15)
       ,@DeliveryCustomerName nvarchar(100)
       ,@DeliveryMobileNo nvarchar(15)
       ,@FromServicePlaceId int
       ,@ToServicePlaceId int       
       ,@TotalAmount money
       ,@ReturnVal int OUTPUT
        )
        AS

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        DECLARE @BookingRate money;
        DECLARE @InwardRate money;
        DECLARE @ToBranch INT;
        DECLARE @ToState INT;
        SET @BookingRate=0;SET @InwardRate=0;SET @ToBranch=0;SET @ToState=0;


        SELECT @ToBranch=ISNULL(a.BranchId,0),@ToState=ISNULL(b.StateId,0) FROM tblService a, tblBranch b WHERE a.BranchId = b.BranchId AND a.ServiceId = @ToServicePlaceId; 
        IF  @Mode='EDIT'
        BEGIN
        SELECT @BranchId = BranchId FROM tblBooking WHERE BookingId = @BookingId;
        END
        SELECT @BookingRate=BookingCommn,@InwardRate=InwardCommn FROM vwCommissionRate WHERE FromBranchId= @BranchId AND ToBranchId = @ToBranch 

        IF  @Mode='ADD'
        BEGIN

            declare @pfx varchar(10)
            set @pfx = CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(DATEADD(MI,330,GETUTCDATE())))+RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), MONTH(DATEADD(MI,330,GETUTCDATE()))), 2)

            SELECT @LRNo =   @pfx + '/' + convert(varchar,convert(int,SUBSTRING(LRNo, CHARINDEX('//', LRNo) + len(@pfx)+2,10))+1) 
            from tblBooking 
            where bookingid = (select MAX(bookingid) from tblbooking where Active =1)

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblBooking]
           ([LRNo]
           ,[BookingDate]
           ,[ReceivedCustomerId]
           ,[SendMobileNo]
           ,[DeliveryCustomerName]
           ,[DeliveryMobileNo]
           ,[FromServicePlaceId]
           ,[ToServicePlaceId]
           ,[TotalAmount]
           ,[BookingCommn]
           ,[InwardCommn] )
        VALUES
           (@LRNo
           ,DATEADD(MI,330,GETUTCDATE())
           ,@ReceivedCustomerId
           ,@SendMobileNo
           ,@DeliveryCustomerName
           ,@DeliveryMobileNo
           ,@FromServicePlaceId
           ,@ToServicePlaceId             
           ,@TotalAmount
           ,@BookingRate    
           ,@InwardRate);
           SET @BookingId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

            END
            ELSE IF  @Mode='EDIT'
            BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo].[tblBooking]
               SET 
                  [ReceivedCustomerId] = @ReceivedCustomerId
                  ,[SendMobileNo] = @SendMobileNo
                  ,[DeliveryCustomerName] = @DeliveryCustomerName
                  ,[DeliveryMobileNo] = @DeliveryMobileNo
                  ,[ToServicePlaceId] = @ToServicePlaceId
                  ,[TotalAmount] = @TotalAmount
                  ,[BookingCommn] = @BookingRate
                  ,[InwardCommn] = @InwardRate
             WHERE BookingId = @BookingId;

            END
            ELSE IF  @Mode='DELETE'
            BEGIN
                ALTER TABLE tblBooking DISABLE TRIGGER [BookingUpdateLog];
                    UPDATE [dbo].[tblBooking] SET Active=0 WHERE BookingId = @BookingId;
                ALTER TABLE tblBooking ENABLE TRIGGER [BookingUpdateLog];

            END

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            SET @ReturnVal = @BookingId;
```

i tried many ways to solve the problem, but could not. How to prevent the duplication

Comment: I'm  not sure I really understand here. Transactions don't stop "duplicate" rows. Unique Constraints and Unique indexes stop duplicate values. Transactions don't control *what* data is effected (in a DML statement), only how/when that data is committed (or not) to the database file.

Comment: One thing that's generally a good idea is to put `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning. This way some errors that you would expect to abort a transaction actually do abort the transaction, instead of just aborting the statement and continuing. This does not itself solve any integrity problems, but may prevent creating more.

Comment: Test query in SQL Server Management Studio and see if you get same results.  I always recommend testing any query in SSMS before trying to use in c#.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tblBooking DISABLE TRIGGER [BookingUpdateLog];` Feels quite odd in  a stored proc. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I am getting duplicate in insert statement only. ie If @Mode=Add      
BookingId      LRNo                   BookingDate                                                                      
672212 202007/238035 2020-07-28 15:07:45.627
672211 202007/238035 2020-07-28 15:07:45.627

See above result. Record insertion at the same time for the difference users. How to prevent this.

Comment: @Larnu I know that Transactions doesn't stop duplication. But at-least it will block other users to insert record un-till  insetion of record.

Comment: @padh nope - a transaction does not prevent selecting the same MAX value from tblBooking. Only luck does this. And there are many other issues you need to address - including the use of [old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and the disabling of triggers. Your trigger should be sufficiently smart to NOT log soft deletes (if this is actually needed).

Comment: And, of course, a unique constraint/index WILL prevent duplicates.